# Speeding up Search API DB search?

Tags: 8, search

I'm using Search API with it's build in Database search, and while the results are much better than the default Drupal search, the speed is quite slow. I'm seeing 10-15 seconds to get the results page to load. Any pointers to speed things up?

Currently there's just under 1,500 items in the index. Happy to get more specific with setup, but any general help would be appreciated to start.

Comment: I think this is going to depend a lot on your index configuration. What parts of content are you indexing? Only the necessary bits? or are you including a lot of extra fluff? Which processors do you have enabled? Some can slow the search down quite a bit.

Comment: Are you also loading results as a string or are you doing entity loads?